# How to see what actually happens for "javascript:;" on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I actually found a website where all buttons just use `href="javascript:;"` as link target. I'm now interested what exactly is happening there and how can I see what different informations are processed, since the buttons behave differently, alltough they all have the same link.

Could you help me figguring out what is done there and how to see that?

Comment: Not really a security question, I'm afraid. You might want to investigate the concept of "event handlers" though - it's possible to have the browser do something upon a specific button being pressed, even if the button itself doesn't make reference to the event that happens.

Comment: @Matthew: Is there a easy way to find the event related to a specific button?

Comment: Not really - you'd have to dig through the scripts on the page looking for references to the button's ID, and work out what was called when it was clicked.

Comment: Well, the browser keeps track of attached event handlers. So with the built-in developer tools you can see which events will be fired.